# Network interfaces and an instance-level private IP address may not be specified on the same request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to create an EC2 instance using boto3 client.run_instances(**parameters) method.
This is the value of my parameters:

```
    {
   "ImageId":"ami-XXXXXXXXX",
   "InstanceType":"m4.large",
   "KeyName":"my_key",
   "UserData":"Content-Type: multipart/mixed",
   "Monitoring":{
      "Enabled":false
   },
   "MaxCount":1,
   "MinCount":1,
   "IamInstanceProfile":{
      "Name":"proxyIp-YYYYYYYY"
   },
   "NetworkInterfaces":[
      {
         "DeviceIndex":0,
         "AssociatePublicIpAddress":true,
         "Groups":[
            "sg-09999999fe111"
         ],
         "SubnetId":"subnet-06XXXXXXXXX"
      }
   ],
   "PrivateIpAddress":"AA.BB.C.DDD",
   "EbsOptimized":true
}
```

However the stack is failing on creation of an ec2 isntance with an error :

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the RunInstances operation: Network interfaces and an instance-level private IP address may not be specified on the same request

Could let me know what is missing. I have checked the parameters they all looks to be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can request a Private IP address *within* the `NetworkInterfaces` block:

```json
            "NetworkInterfaces": [
                {
                    "PrivateDnsName": "ip-10-0-0-157.us-east-2.compute.internal",
                    "PrivateIpAddress": "10.0.0.157",
                    "SourceDestCheck": true,
                    "Status": "in-use",
                    "SubnetId": "subnet-04a636d18e83cfacb",
                    "VpcId": "vpc-1234567890abcdef0",
                }
            ],
```